# Make JQuery control states persistent after AJAX updates the DOM

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using Asp.net MVC. I have implemented SignalR to make the application process database updates to the client in real-time. I do this by calling a client script function which makes an ajax call to return a partial view to a div tag.

Next I have added JQuery javascript to enhance the organization of my data tables. Keeping things simple for now, I'm just toggling the visibility on child rows and tables... etc...

The issue should now be obvious. When the server processes a post request and tells the client to fetch new data, it refreshes the DOM and resets the visibility of HTML objects to their default state. Completely expected.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to easily store the state of these controls either by cookies, or other means, so that, say a person viewing details of a particular row does not have their view collapse on them unexpectedly, yet still receives the updated data. As a note, the data structure largely remains the same, there is not a lot of adding new rows, new tables, etc... Just updates of data objects which already exist on the page.

The code: (If I've left anything pertinent out, please request.)

Main View: (div tag where partial is returned and SignalR client code)

```
@model xxxx.Models.SystemModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "System Details";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="systemDetails">
            @Html.Action("GetDetails", "Monitoring", Model.Customer.SONumber)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="/Scripts/systemdetails.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.monitoringHub;

        //debugger;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateDetails = function (sonumber) {
            getDetails(sonumber)
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            //alert("connection started")
            getDetails(@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString());
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });

    function getDetails(sonumber) {
        if(sonumber = (@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString())){
            var tbl = $('#systemDetails');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Monitoring/GetDetails/@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString()',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'
            }).success(function (result) {
                tbl.empty().append(result);
            }).error(function () {

            });
        }
    }
</script>
}
```

Jquery script: (This is not optimized, but it works for a mutually exclusive row toggle. The second click event toggles the entire table.)

```
     $("#systemDetails").on("click", "#deviceDetail", function () {
    if ($(this).closest('tr').next().is(':hidden')) {
        $("[id^=child]").hide();
        $("[id^=deviceDetail]").removeClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
        $("[id^=deviceDetail]").addClass('glyphicon-plus-sign');
        $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign");
    }
    else {
        $("[id^=child]").hide();
        $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign");
    }
});

$("#systemDetails").on("click", "#categoryToggle", function () {
    $(this).closest('table').next().toggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign");
});
```

Relevant sample of the partial view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Devices.Where(d => d.Room == category))
    {
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="deviceDetail"></span>
            </td>
    (...)
        <tr style="display:none" id="child">
    (...)
```